# Java RMI class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class client.MessageServerInt

Tags: java, rmi

Edit: So even after changing them all to the same package, still getting the error. So not package related.

I'm doing an RMI client/server project for school. The teacher says the Server/Client must be in different packages, which I believe is why I'm having this issue. Just gonna leave out error handling (try/catch) for space. Server runs fine. I think the server and client being in two different packages is causing issues, but unsure how to actually fix it as the server and client are in two different locations (machines).

Full error message is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class client.MessageServerInt (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 and client.MessageServerInt are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Interface

```
package server;
import java.rmi.*

public interface MessageServerInt extends Remote {
public boolean auth();
}
```

Server

```
package server;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MessageServerInt {
public Server() throws RemoteException {

}

public boolean auth() {
return true;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
MessageServerInt srv= new Server();
Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/Server", srv);
}
}
```

Client

```
package client;
import java.rmi.*;
import server.MessageServerInt;

public class Client {

public static void main(String args[]) {
MessageServerInt stub = (MessageServerInt)Naming.lookup("//localhost:1099/server");
}

}
```

Comment: You have two copies of the remote interface in different packages. That means they aren't the same. Don't do that. You need a single remote interface, shared somehow between client and server. You can create a shared package, or even a shared project between them if your IDE and environment permit.

Comment: Praise you
-- ASU Student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully someone can save some time by learning from my mistakes.
The problem was a package problem, but ended up being due to a leftover interface compiled under the client package.

So when my client attempted to access the rmi interface, it ran into a duplicate and gave off the above error.

The lesson to be learned here? Delete your class files once in awhile if you make structural changes or are having issues. Definitely feel stupid fighting this for so long.

Comment: ..but what if we have two different applications for server and a client, hence we compile interfaces separately?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Use a shared project for the shared interfaces and anything they rely on.